# Hidden toolbar in Dolphin

Tags: kde, dolphin

I have accidentally hidden the toolbar in Dolphin. How can I get it back? I cannot find any option to restore it.

Comment: you can press the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + M, which enables you to recover Dolphin

Comment: Actually no - this toggles the menu bar, but not the toolbar (the one with icon buttons). What I actually had to do is rightclicking up to a few pixels below the titlebar - that's where the empty toolbar is still present and popup menu can be triggered to shot it back.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else has that problem, I've found the answer.

You need to rightclick right under the title bar. A narow, empty toolbar is still there even it it cannot be seen. A context menu will show up, where the toolbar can be toggled back on.

Answer (score 1):

If the menu is hidden, use `Ctrl + M` to unhide it.

When the menu is showing, check `Settings > Show Toolbar`.